# Data binding between enum to ComboBox

Tags: c#

```
Public Class Person
{
 private enum accountType
 {
   Savings,
   Cheking
 },

}
```

In Windows form I have a comboBox Account Type.
How can i bind data from Person Class to Windows form combobox. When I run the form combobox will show the enum list automatically. How can i solve it. Anybody help me.
One portion enum accountType will be public. I am new in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Hei i hope this could help you

```
      public enum AccountType
      {
         Savings,
         Cheking
      }
```

Write the following code in your Form1.cs file
I am assuming your Form name is Form1

```
    public Form1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindComboList();
    }

    private void BindComboList()
    {
        var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(AccountType));
        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            cmbAccountType.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

You are done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
cbaccountType.DataSource=Enum.GetValues(typeof(accountType));
```

where cbaccountType is you ComboBox.